# AJAX logout does not work when tab is closed

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to logout the user if the user is closing a tab. I've tried to do this by calling an ajax function on the `onbeforeunload` method:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            if (!validNavigation) { // I set validNavigation = true when user clicks on different internal links etc
                LogOff();
            }
        }
    });

    var validNavigation = false;

function LogOff() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        data: {  },
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/Account/LogOffAjax',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (resp) {
            if (resp.IsSuccessful) {
            }
            else {
                alert(resp.ExceptionKey);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('unknown error');
        }
    });

};
```

Method LogOffAjax calls without any exception inside (checked by debugger), but the user stays logged in. If I call this method when user simply clicks on the link (not closing the tab) - user is logged out (so the method works correctly). I assume cookies can't be cleared when the tab is closed (but it's very strange why the server "thinks" the user is still logged in).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the server doesn't track logged in users.  The .ASPXAUTH cookie that's submitted with all requests is checked to see if the user is still authenticated.

If the user's browser session has ended, the server can't remove their .ASPXAUTH cookie.  If you want to ensure it works, you can delete the cookie from the client side within your LogOff function or `beforeunload` handler.

**Edit:** Depending on what version of ASP.NET MVC you're using, you might be looking at `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`

Comment: `.ASPXAUTH` - this should exist.  Does it?  Either that or `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`, if you're using ASP.NET MVC 5

Answer (score 2):

Ajax requests performed in the onbeforeunload method must be synchronous, otherwise they will not finish before the redirect happens.

```
...
async: false,
...
```

Also note, your alerts in the success and error will not happen.